# EPPLUS - The file is not a valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please

Tags: excel, epplus

The application that generated this error had been working for the past year on my clients site. Yesterday it threw the "not a valid Package file" error.  Luckily I had captured the error and included the file name that it was trying to open.  The name of the file and the fact that the application had already opened the file and did some 'work' gave me a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

The file name that errored started with ~$ which I knew to be a temporary file that MS creates when a file is open.  For some reason, my code was now including the temp file in the list of files in the folder.  A month ago, it was not.

My quick fix was to continue the for loop if the file started with '~'.

Can anyone shed some light on what has changed in the past month to cause this to become an issue?

Also, if there is a better way to resolve this, please share.