# C# EPPLUS: ~$ xlsx file "is not a valid Package file"

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to read all the excel files within a folder. Here is part of my code:

```
string[] arrStatements = Directory.GetFiles(localPath, "*.xlsx");
 foreach (var statement in arrStatements)
 {
   FileInfo excelFilee = new FileInfo(statement));
   processedStage = excelFilee.ToString();
   using (ExcelPackage excell = new ExcelPackage(excelFilee))
   //...
```

This gives me the "The file is not a valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor" error. This only happens to 1 single file, and when I check my error log, it has a "~$" at the start of its file name, which isn't present when I check properties of the file. I have read that the "~$" indicates that this is a temporary lock file or owner file - I am not sure how this works, but I can't really do much with the file itself as I am supposed to read the files uploaded by others without editing the files or changing anything in the folder.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141537/epplus-the-file-is-not-a-valid-package-file-if-the-file-is-encrypted-please) but this isn't exactly my issue? I use a foreach loop and whether the file name contains "~$" shouldn't affect the loop, right? If my understanding is correct then the ~$ file is still read but the program deems it as a invalid file because it is a temporary lock file. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: those `~$` files are just created to say that the file is being opened. If Excel crashed or killed before it was able to remove the lock files then they'll exist. They don't contain spreadsheet contents, just check the size and you'll see they're pretty tiny. Just remove or ignore them

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I actually copied the files directly from a network shared folder into a local directory for testing. I have checked the content of these files and all of them contain templates and references that I need to use. If I read directly from the network folder, will the file be read normally, or will the issue still exist that I have to work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding that the "~$" file is a temporary lock file created by Microsoft Office applications when a document is open. It's not meant to be directly opened or processed as a regular Excel file. This file is used to store information about the user who has the document open and is automatically managed by Office applications.

In your case, you can filter out these temporary lock files before attempting to process the Excel files. Here's how you can modify your code to skip processing of files with names starting with "~$":

```
string[] arrStatements = Directory.GetFiles(localPath, "*.xlsx");
foreach (var statement in arrStatements)
{
    // Check if the file name starts with "~$" and skip processing if it does
    if (Path.GetFileName(statement).StartsWith("~$"))
    {
        continue;
    }

    FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(statement);
    processedStage = excelFile.ToString();
    
    try
    {
        using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
        {
            // Process the Excel file
            // ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions related to processing the Excel file
        // ...
    }
}
```

By using the **Path.GetFileName** method and checking if the file name starts with "~$", you can easily identify and skip temporary lock files. The rest of your processing logic should remain intact.

Keep in mind that while the "~$" files are temporary lock files, it's always a good practice to implement proper error handling in your code when working with files, especially when processing a batch of files like in your scenario. This ensures that any unexpected issues are properly handled and reported without crashing your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask if the temporary files are absolutely unreadable and must be skipped? I have just realized that my colleagues had uploaded the temporary lock file of a template instead of the actual(?) file. If that is the case then I will have to talk to them...

Comment: Temporary lock files (denoted by names starting with "~$") are not meant to be directly opened or processed as regular Excel files. These files are created by Microsoft Office applications to manage document locking and sharing information among users who have the document open. They do not contain the actual content of the Excel document.

Comment: These temporary lock files typically contain metadata about who is currently editing the document, the time the document was opened, and similar information. As such, attempting to read or process these files like regular Excel files will likely result in errors or unexpected behavior.

Comment: In general, it's a best practice to skip processing these temporary lock files when iterating through files in a folder, as they don't contain meaningful data for your intended tasks.

If you need to process Excel files, focus on the files with valid names that don't start with "~$". These files will contain the actual content you're interested in working with. Temporary lock files are just artifacts of the collaboration and file locking mechanisms used by Microsoft Office applications.

Comment: Okay I guess there really isn't a way to process them then...Thanks again for your reply